# How to save options at the game?

Tags: unity, c#

In my game main character can move using tap or hold finger on the screen. I wanna create at the menu options, and there button to change control type.
How I can save player choose? Using Prefs?

Answer (score 1):

What input mode to use is a typical player preference. As such, it should be saved in the [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) class. PlayerPrefs is a key/value store. It allows you to store and retrieve variables (int, float or string) under string-keys of your choice. It uses a platform-appropriate persistent storage method, so it doesn't just survive scene reloads but also closing and relaunching the whole game application.

Comment: Where can I find some information about this? Can you give me a link or something?

Comment: @AndreyDubchak I already gave you a link in my answer. The documentation should tell you everything you need to know. When you have trouble understanding it, please ask a new question.

Comment: That link is all the information you should need in order to understand how to use PlayerPrefs.